# Partition of $E \times E$ ond equivalence relations

Tags: equivalence-relations

I'ts know that given a partition of $E$ we can construct an equivalence relation on $E$. (a subset of $E^2$)

My question: if we had a partition of $E^2$ how do we define an equivalence relation on $E$. (a subset of $E^4$)

Comment: Why would a partition of $E^2$ give an equivalence relation on $E$? Why would $E$ be a subset of $E^4$? Or did you mean $E^2$ when you wrote $E$? And if so why not just let $F=E^2$ reducing to a problem already solved?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm trying to deal with the problem that not already solved

Comment: And I'm trying to understand why you are writing that an equivalence relation on $E$ is a subset of $E^4$.

Comment: by detention a binary relation on $E$ is a subsets of  $E^2$. Let's call this one quadrany relation ?

Comment: OK, a partition of $E^2$ defines a subset of $E^4$ in exactly the same way that a partition of $E$ defines a subset of $E^2$. Just let $F=E^2$, reducing to a problem already solved. (detention? definition?)

Comment: that would give me a relation over $F=E^2$. I want a relation over $E$

Comment: OK, you want a 4-place relation on $E$. Then: if $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are in the same part of the partition of $E^2$, then $(a,b,c,d)$ is in the 4-place relation on $E$.

Comment: Is that OK, TWJ?

Comment: Are you still here, TWJ?

Comment: sorry i didn't see your comment, we define a 2-place relation as follow $(a,b)$ are in the relation iff there an element of the partition that contains $a$ and $b$. how can we define it for the 4-place relation

Comment: $(a,b,c,d)$ is in the 4-place relation if and only if there is an element of the partition that contains both $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$.

Comment: It would be difficult to define transitivity on that

Comment: You're making me crazy. You want an equivalence relation on $E$. An equivalence relation on $E$ is a subset of $E^2$. But you want your equivalence relation to be a subset of $E^4$. Next, you'll be asking for a triangle with four sides, and a two-digit number exceeding $100$.

Comment: in the literature the [n-ary relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitary_relation) are known. a relation don't have to be binary, and a polygon don't need to be triangle

Comment: If you are so on top of the literature, then why are you asking questions here? Does the literature say anything about subsets of $E^4$ as equivalence relations on $E$?

Comment: no it dosen't. Now i see that my question dosen't make a lot of sens. i was hoping someone have a straightforward answer. i just realized  that it don't exist

Comment: Good. Maybe you could write up an explanation of why it doesn't exist, and post that as an answer.

Comment: i don't think many people are interested in why it dosen't exist a triangle with 4 legs